# Rails Unit Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing

Please help.  I am trying to write a unit test for a method in my model.  It keeps giving me the following error:

{ 1) Error:
test_Total_for_a_given_date_range_for_Campaigns(LetterTest):
TypeError: can't convert ActiveSupport::Duration into String
    c:/Users/Kay/rails-app/CS5942/app/models/letter.rb:19:in `+'
    c:/Users/Kay/rails-app/CS5942/app/models/letter.rb:19:in`tribe_total_on'
    test/unit/letter_test.rb:17:in `block in '}

This is what i have in my test file:

```
test "Total for a given date range for Campaigns" do        
  end_date = (Date.today + 1.day).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  expected = Letter.where("letter_campaign_id = '1' and created_at between '#{ (Date.today - 1.day).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}' and #{end_date}").count
  data = Letter.tribe_total_on( 1 , (Date.today - 1.day).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') , (Date.today).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

  assert_equal expected, data
end
```

It seems to have a problem with the plus sign.  I would be very happy if i could find a solution to it.  Thanks.

This is the tribe_total_on method:

```
def self.tribe_total_on(tribe, start_date, end_date)
  #Letter.connection.execute("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM letters WHERE letter_campaign_id = #{tribe} AND created_at BETWEEN '#{start_date.to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}' and '#{end_date.to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}'")[0][0]
  end_date = end_date + 1.day #This is line 19 ...Had to include the one day to accomodate dates like 2011-06-05 01:02:03

  Letter.where("letter_campaign_id = #{tribe} AND created_at between ? and ?", start_date.to_date, end_date.to_date).count
end
```

Comment: It's not coming from your test, it's coming from your Letter model (as the error says).  What is on line 19 of letter.rb? (Post the entire tribe_total_on method and point out which one is line 19).

Comment: Thanks.. Have posted the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up Rails console and type in what you're trying to do and you'll get this:

> > (Date.today).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + 1.day
> >     TypeError: can't convert ActiveSupport::Duration into String
> >         from (irb):20:in `+'

You're either going to have to do the conversion to strftime before you pass it to tribe_total_on or you're going to have to add 1.day to the date before you call strftime before you pass it to tribe_total_on.

So:

```
(Date.today + 1.day).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

or:

```
def self.tribe_total_on(tribe, start_date, end_date)
  end_date = (end_date + 1.day).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: I have tried the code but it still gives me the error, i suspect that it sees end_date as a string in the method and not a date value. what do you think?

Comment: Oh..Thanks a lot for your help....i re-wrote it like this and it worked..                                                       end_date = ((end_date).to_date + 1.day).to_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: @Peter DeWeese...Please am new to this, how do i do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is a check mark outline to the left of the answer that you can click to select the best answer.